# Installing a driver via pnputil

Tags: windows, driver, nsis, inf

I'm trying to install an .inf file via NSIS like ([Installing a driver in NSIS script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293299/installing-a-driver-in-nsis-script)).

Installation itself works smooth, but Windows installs the driver with its internal *published name* (an incrementing number oemxxx.inf).

How can I get pnputil.exe to give me the published name as return value (for later usage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to get the published drivername in nsis is this hell of a workaround:

1. put the list of installed drivers to a text-file via `pnputil /e > driverlist_before.txt`
2. install new driver via `pnputil /i /a mydriver.inf`
3. put the list of installed drivers to a text-file via `pnputil /e > driverlist_after.txt`
4. put following code in a .cmd file and execute it via `nsExec`

content of `GetPublishedDrivername.cmd`

```
@echo off
:: look at differences between files and just keep the line with the oem info
fc mydriverlist_before.txt mydriverlist_after.txt | findstr /C:"oem" > diff.txt
:: cut result and keep second part               "           oem##.inf"
for /f "tokens1,2 delims=:" %%a in (diff.txt) do (
  if "%%a"=="Published name " set info=%%b
)
:: get rid of leading spaces                     "oem##.inf"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%info%") do set info=%%a
:: split "oem##.inf" and keep first part         "oem##"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%info%") do set info=%%a 
:: get of the oem part                           "##"
set info=%info:oem=%
:: convert string into int value
set /a info=%info%
del diff.txt
:: return number as result
exit /b %info%
```

This script can surely be optimized, every input is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**I think that is not possible**. Here is a list of all commands of PnPUtil:

Microsoft PnP Utility

### Usage:

pnputil.exe **[-f | -i] [ -? | -a | -d | -e ]**

Examples:

pnputil.exe -a a:\usbcam\USBCAM.INF      -> Add package specified by USBCAM.INF

pnputil.exe -a c:\drivers*.inf          -> Add all packages in c:\drivers\

pnputil.exe -i -a a:\usbcam\USBCAM.INF   -> Add and install driver package

pnputil.exe -e                           -> Enumerate all 3rd party packages

pnputil.exe -d oem0.inf                  -> Delete package oem0.inf

pnputil.exe -f -d oem0.inf               -> Force delete package oem0.inf

pnputil.exe -?                           -> This usage screen

So you cannot extract that information and pass it to NSIS easily :(

Answer (score 1):

Pnputil won't do it, but you can get details about the oem(number).inf file by doing

```
     dism /online /get-driverinfo /driver:oem(number).inf
```

You will get back a listing like:

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

Driver package information:

Published Name : oem3.inf
Driver Store Path : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\us003.inf_amd64_daf71ec003559d2a\us003.inf
Class Name : Printer
Class Description : Printers
Class GUID : {4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Date : 9/14/2015
Version : 3.0.3.0
Boot Critical : No

Drivers for architecture : x86

```
Manufacturer : Samsung
Description : Samsung Universal Print Driver 3
Architecture : x86
Hardware ID : USBPRINT\SamsungML-21500EDE
Service Name : 
Compatible IDs : 
Exclude IDs : 

Manufacturer : Samsung
Description : Samsung Universal Print Driver 3
Architecture : x86
Hardware ID : WSDPRINT\SamsungML-21500EDE
Service Name : 
Compatible IDs : 
Exclude IDs : 

Manufacturer : Samsung
Description : Samsung Universal Print Driver 3
Architecture : x86
Hardware ID : USBPRINT\SamsungSCX-6x45_Seri402B
Service Name : 
Compatible IDs : 
Exclude IDs :
```

.... with maybe many others

Comment: This output is similarly useless as the one from PNPUtil, so I'm not sure how your answer helps with the posted question?

Comment: It helps you match the "useless" numerical name generated by PNPUtil /e in Slappy's comment to actual information about the hardware.

Comment: but how does that help with the NSIS script (the initial question)?

Comment: Point made, that should have been separated into COMMENTS rather than posted as an ANSWER.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe this answer is still useful for someone...
This is what I use:

```
SET OEMNUM=-1
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,200) DO (
dism /online /get-driverinfo /driver:oem%%G.inf >temp.txt
find "something.inf" temp.txt >nul && SET OEMNUM=%%G
)
pnputil /delete-driver oem%oemnum%.inf /force
```

Basically it checks the details of every OEM# until it finds the INF you are looking for and then, using pnputil, deletes it.
If it isn't there, pnputil will attempt to delete "oem-1.inf", which does not exists (it goes from 0 to infinity).